# "UIScreen' doesn't have the member 'main'

Tags: swift3, uiscreen

Environment:

Xcode Version 8.1 beta (8T47) 
Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.56 clang-800.0.42)

The Swift 3.0.1 compiler  flagged 'UIScreen' as '...no member'.
[image]

...but the UIScreen file does have 'main':

@available(iOS 2.0, *)
open class UIScreen : NSObject, UITraitEnvironment {

```
@available(iOS 3.2, *)
open class var screens: [UIScreen] { get } // all screens currently attached to the device

open class var main: UIScreen { get } // the device's internal screen
```

I found numerous instances of a particular class not having a certain member. 
And this was after converting the code to Swift 3.0.1 thru Xcode helper conversion function.  
What gives?

---

Note: I was able to access UIScreen.main.scale via playground. 
It appears that I'm working with a corrupt swift file.

Comment: try UIScreen().scale

Answer (score 3):

**Swift3.0.1** Since **UIScreen** is  **UIKit** framework's class.So make sure you have imported.

```
import UIKit
```